# How repeatable should eigen's completeOrthogonalDecomposition and colPivHouseholderQr solutions be?

Tags: eigen

I am solving some Mx=b linear problems with eigen, and have noticed that I am sometimes getting different results each time I run the program even when I run the same program on the same data.

I am fully aware that there are plenty of bad things which I myself could have done that would lead to such issues (including, but not limited to, failures to initialise things properly, memory overruns, operations with undefined behaviour, etc).  I do not expect users to debug my code.

But what I am interested to know is:

"Are there any places where eigen's solve routines default to doing things (e.g. choosing pivots) in such a way that the choices could differ between identical program invocations? (E.g. this could happen if random numbers were needed and these were seeding off the clock or /dev/random, etc.)"

In other words: are there ever circumstances when a user who has written a bug-free program, in which everything is initialised correctly, and who has not fiddled with random seeds, could reasonably expect to get different results from eigen-solve each time the same program binary is run on bit-for-bit identical inputs on the same computer?

[This is not the same as asking is there repeatable randomness in eigen. E.g. if a linear equation has two solutions and eigen randomly picks one of them (as indeed it may) then that's not the kind of randomness I'm talking about if the `random' choices is always the same random choice.]

Comment: I note that an old answer here https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=130923 suggests that the answer to my question is "no : identical eigen runs produce the same result". But perhaps that result is no longer current.

Comment: Provided that there is not a bug in CPU and that there is no bug in Eigen itself also the answer is NO.